# How can we accommodate arbitrary Unicode characters in symbol names?

Tags: programming, symbols, named-characters

I understand why *Mathematica* doesn't the support the `[` character in symbol names, but it should be escapable in some way, like non-printable characters are in strings using `\`. A bigger problem is that a large number of Unicode characters are also not allowed in symbol names, and some of them for no obvious reason.

Is there a good way to escape such characters? Ideally, it should be broadly usable in arbitrary *Mathematica* code without requiring further special handling of the escaped symbol names.

I'm thinking something like the following:

```
Replace[a$multiply$[b[c, d]], 
 head_[x___] :> $[
        StringReplace[ToString@head, {"$multiply$" :> "*"}]][x], {0, 
  Infinity}]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question but merely a rant about how the OP would like to change the behavior of _Mathematica_

Comment: @m_goldberg But what if I can patch it to something like a posted used the dollarsign character?  I'll let you close it, but I will probably repost it once I get a somewhat working solution.

Comment: @M_goldberg If I get one more downvote I'm probably going to delete it for now.

Comment: While allowing arbitrary characters in symbols is perhaps not a good idea (could lead to ambiguities in interpretation), I for one do not see any "rant" here, so +1 to offset down-votes I do not think warranted.

Comment: I edited your question to try to make it more accessible, since I had to read carefully to discover what you were really getting at and understand that it is a valid and useful thing to want. If you do not like the edits, please roll back as appropriate, but in my opinion it is a more idiomatic question when posed this way. You also have my upvote, not for offsetting reasons but because it is a good question in its essence.

Comment: Also, in case I misunderstood your intent, I hope you are aware that it is possible to have symbols *print as* something that they are not? Look at `FormatValues`, `InterpretationBox`, &c. It is no problem to define a symbol `aTimes` that prints as `a×` (or whatever you want).

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks for the edit.  Yes but with `FormatValues`,`InterprationBox` its not editable I believe.  I hacked something together with `ToBoxes` for fun at one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is in the right direction if you include the answer to invalid Symbol characters also.

```
opts = {"$divide$" :> "/", "$backslash$" :> "\\", "$period$" :> ".", 
   "$tilde$" :> "~", "$backtick$" :> "`", "$exclaim$" :> "!", 
   "$at$" :> "@", "$number$" :> "#", "$dollar$" :> "$", 
   "$percent$" :> "%", "$caret$" :> "^", "$amp$" :> "&", 
   "$multiply$" :> "*", "$parenleft$" :> "(", "$parenright$" :> ")", 
   "$underscore$" :> "_", "$dash$" :> "-", "$plus$" :> "+", 
   "$equal$" :> "=", "$barleft$" :> "[", "$barright$" :> "]", 
   "$bracketleft$" :> "{", "$bracketright$" :> "}", "$colon$" :> ":", 
   "$semicolon$" :> ";", "$singlequote$" :> "'", 
   "$doublequote$" :> "\"", "$lessthan$" :> "<", "$comma$" :> ",", 
   "$period$" :> ".", "$slash$" :> "/", "$question$" :> "?", 
   "$space$" :> " ", "$n$" :> "\n", "$r$" :> "\r"};
opts = Join[
   Drop[Quiet[
     Cases[Symbol[FromCharacterCode[#]] & /@ Range[0, 16^4 - 1], 
      Symbol[z__] -> (StringJoin@
          Flatten@Join[{"$", IntegerString[ToCharacterCode[z], 16, 4],
              "$"}] -> z)]], 1], opts];
Replace[a$multiply$[b$underscore$[c, d]], 
 head_[x___] :> $[StringReplace[ToString@head, opts]][x], {0, 
  Infinity}]
```

If you would like to display it in a pretty form you can do the following.

```
ReplaceRepeated[
 ToBoxes[FullForm@Ti$at$mes[{a}, Rational[1, -2], "test"]][[1, 
   1]], {RowBox[{b_String, "[", x___String, "]"}] :> 
   StringJoin[{StringReplace[b, opts], "[", x, "]"}], 
  RowBox[{b___String}] :> StringJoin[{b}]}]
```