# Can symbols like + or * be used to denote the Plus and Times functions?

Tags: syntax, custom-notation

Can one do something similar to `+[1, 2]`? The point is that with **one symbol** you would be able to write expressions like `#/+@@# &@{1, 2, 3}` and yet benefit from Mathematica's algebraic capabilities, so that expressions like 1+1*2 would output 3 not 4.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? I mean, +[1,2] is not even shorter than writing 1+2.

Comment: Its more functional style.

Comment: Plus[1,2] would be more functional style.

Comment: It's more terse functional style.

Comment: Here is a way to accomidate all unicode characters which I believe is kinda the intent of the question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94349/how-can-we-accommodate-arbitrary-unicode-characters-in-symbol-names

Comment: Now, if you can get rid of the brackets and go full Polish...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The point is that with **one symbol** you would be able to write expressions like `+@@#&/@{{1,2},{3,4}}` and yet benefit from Mathematica's algebraic capabilities, so that expressions like `1+1*2` would output 3 not 4.

Comment: `1+1*2` already outputs `3`.

Comment: Yes, but `#/+@@# &@{1, 2, 3}` doesn't output {1/6, 1/3, 1/2}. You can't use the same symbol for both infix and function head.

Comment: Well, that's what `Normalize[]` was meant for…

Comment: Such terseness is just not in the nature of *Mathematica*. If you're really looking for that kind of symbolic terseness, you might take a look at the free J programming language (http://jsoftware.com); in that language, `+/ 2 3 4` gives result `9`, and `*/2 3 4` the result `24` (and `^/ 2 3 4` the result `2.41785e24`, where what `^/` does is to insert the power operator `^` between successive items of its argument).

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `Notation` [package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html). It requires a GUI palette though.

```
Needs["Notation`"]
```

Once you have this package loaded, you can use the template to define:

```
Notation[+[x___] ==> Plus[x___]]
```

and then

```
+[1,2,3]
(* 6 *)
```

Similarly,

```
Notation[*[x___] ==> Times[x___]]
```

and so

```
*[2,3,4]
(* 24 *)
```

Note: A `*` typed as the first character of a cell converts it to an  "Item Cell."

Comment: Quite useful edit. I also propose to write `x___` to handle zero number of arguments (sometimes it is useful).

Comment: @EricBrown Since Mathematica 10, typing `*` as the first character on the line converts it to an item cell. It's similar to how typing `=` as the first character is also special.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's what it is!  Thanks.  I was confused because I had Notation working for * then not.

Answer (score 9):

For `Plus`, there's this, from [How would I add together any list of arguments as a pure function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27553/how-would-i-add-together-any-list-of-arguments-as-a-pure-function/27554#27554):

```
+Sequence[1, 2, 3]
(*  6  *)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use any character without built-in meaning like `＋` or `＊` (they differ from standard `+` and `*`). However, it is difficult to type them. So I propose to use meaningful Greek letters `Σ` and `Π` with shortcuts <kbd>Esc</kbd>S<kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>P<kbd>Esc</kbd> respectively

```
Σ = Plus;
Π = Times;
Σ[1, 2]
Π[1, 2]
(* 3 *)
(* 2 *)
```

You can use this notation in other syntax constructions

```
Π @@ {1, 2, 3, 4}
(* 24 *)
```

Comment: You know, `Plus` is just one more keystroke and escape is far from home row.  I'm rather with Sjoerd on this.

Comment: Or how about p=Plus; t=Times; Fewer strokes, easier to remember.

Comment: @bills It was my first thought, but I decided that it is not very intuitive.

Comment: It would be most useful if what ever symbol is used to denote summation would be used for both infix notation, like `1+1`, and for function Head, like `+[1,1]`. Could one use one of these symbols in place of the current + symbol everywhere?

Comment: Sure you can write `1~Plus~1~Times~2`, but the evaluation order isn't right: the output of the previous expression is 4 not 3.